# Testing multiple classes with 1 test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

Say I have an interface with 2 classes that both implement it. So we have interface I, with classes A and B. For these 2 classes, we need to test the same implemented function, doSomething() with JUnit4. There's some dependencies, so we're using Mockito. An example test looks like:

```
@Mock private dependantClass d;

@Test
public void test() {
    A.doSomething();
    verify(d).expectedBehavior();
}
```

I've written the test suite for A (4 tests), no problems. However, now I have to restructure the test suite so I can execute the same test class on both A and B objects. For this, I should use a parallel class hierarchy.

This has left me stumped. I've tried using the @Parameters annotation, but this gives me the error that I have too many input arguments. I've tried making a super test class that both ATest and BTest extend from, but I'm guessig I'm not doing it right because I get nullpointer exceptions.

Actually copying all test cases and just changing A to B passes all the tests, that's to say that these 2 classes do the same. I realize that that sounds like faulty design, and to be honest, it probably is. However, I do not have the possibility to actually alter the code, I just have to test it.

Am I just doing things wrong? How should I implement this?

Comment: Please show how you tried to parameterize your tests. It's the right approach, and you probably missed something small.

Comment: I wonder why [parameterized-tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) failed in your case. Could you post a snippet on your try on that?

Comment: This is a fairly common use case for @Parameters so you might need to show some details of that try. The 'too many input arguments' might be a simple error (such as a mismatch with the constructor's signature) that could be diagnosed if you post that code.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I've worked out the error.

It was a mismatch with the constructor's signature as @sprinter suggested, combined with a fault in my annotations. The combination left me clueless.

Thanks to all 3 of you for confirming the Parameters approach was the right one, I've now got it down. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try out JUnit Theories:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class AdditionWithTheoriesTest {
  private dependantClass d;

  @Before
  public void before() {
    d = mock(dependantClass);
  }

  @DataPoints
  public static I[] positiveIntegers() {
    return new I[]{
      new A(d),          //inject d into A, may differ
      new B(d)           //inject d into B, may differ
    };

  }

  @Theory
  public void test(I data) {
    data.doSomething();
    verify(d).expectedBehavior();
  }
```

The same can be done with `@Parameters` (if configured correctly). Yet `@Parameters` is more suitable for testing one class with multiple data. `@Theories` is meant for asserting same behavior on different arguments (e.g. multiple classes).

Comment: You probably mean `data.doSomething()` And your are accessing `d` from static context, this will not work